# Почему nodejs устанавливается неправильно?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

Что делаю я -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Затем -

```
sudo node -v
```

выводит

```
ivan@pc:~$ sudo node -v
sudo: node: command not found
ivan@pc:~$ 

node -v
```

выводит

```
ivan@pc:~$ node -v
bash: /usr/bin/node: Нет такого файла или каталога
ivan@pc:~$
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Для линуксов есть nvm.
Она позволит легче управлять версиями node и не требует root доступа для глобальных пакетов


https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: @Алексей Привалов гугл говорит, что n круче чем nmv.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nodejs` - опубликуйте ее вывод

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-file search nodejs | grep nodejs | grep bin
```

Выдаёт среди прочего `nodejs: /usr/bin/nodejs`. ОС ubuntu 14.04.

Соответственно надо писать не `ivan@pc:~$ node -v`, а `ivan@pc:~$ nodejs -v`

Comment: судя по ответу, Вы просто вообще не в теме ноды :)

Comment: Ну так опиши понятнее что ты хочешь. Я ответил не на то, что ты имел ввиду, а то, что ты написал в вопросе. Улавливаешь разницу?

Comment: @shatal с учетом того, что `node` - симлинк на `nodejs`, имеет смысл попробовать, как советует don Rumata (проверить `nodejs -v` и наличие пакета в системе вообще)